# Find the number of business day between 2 date in an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Some background: Have a list of incidents which were open on a certain day and closed on a certain date, this data is kept in an excel sheet.

My issue: I need to find the no of working days (ie count of days excluding sat and sun) in between the date given in the excel sheet.

My question: Is there an inbuild function in excel which checks the calender and gives this needed output.

Comment: there is a function `Datediff`. but beware it rounds to upper number (meaning if for example you look for the difference in months, 2 months and 1 day would give 3 months, i had this problem once).

Comment: The function NETWORKDAYS help. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## NETWORKDAYS function
>
> ### Description
>
> Returns the number of whole working days between `start_date` and `end_date`. Working days exclude weekends and any dates identified in holidays. Use `NETWORKDAYS` to calculate employee benefits that accrue based on the number of days worked during a specific term.
>
> TIP:  To calculate whole workdays between two dates by using parameters to indicate which and how many days are weekend days, use the `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` function.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> `NETWORKDAYS(start_date, end_date, [holidays])`
>
> The `NETWORKDAYS` function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> - `Start_date` Required. A date that represents the start date.
> - `End_date` Required. A date that represents the end date.
> - `Holidays` Optional. An optional range of one or more dates to exclude from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contains the dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that represent the dates.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Have you noticed that between two years it detects 262 days with no further input when there should be 259? There are 52+53 variable Saturdays/Sundays in a year?